# Add custom html to a facet api facet block

Tags: search

How can i add custom html to a [facet api](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi) facet block. Like a link to another page or some descriptive text and an image. It would be good for user experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own facet widget. Just extends from one of existing widgets. You can found examples in module facetapi.

Comment: yes. but then i can not use existing widgets like range slider etc. i only want to add some html text. doing my own widget just for this and all existing widgets cant be used anymore.

Comment: Some widgets use theme function for render his content. You can redefine this function in your theme and include text in this theme function in some situations.

Comment: redefine? you mean copy the theme function from a widget that for example does range, and then add my text? then i would have to that for all widgets i have/use. with will be 5. i altered the settings page now and added my custom textfield for the text. now i must somehow insert it into the output, not as a widget as i want to still use my ranged widget.